# Does the latest version of iOS automatically sync the Exchange Global Address List?

Tags: contacts, ios, iphone, exchange-activesync

An executive at my company has the iPhone 6 with iOS 8.4.  For a month or two now he's noticed that any changes he makes to employee contacts eventually get reverted, and it's driving him (and, consequently, me) crazy.

After some experimentation, we've learned that his contacts are being overwritten by entries from our Exchange Global Address List.  It may take a day or two for it to happen after he's edited a contact.  And once the contact has been reverted, it will also revert his contact in Outlook thanks to Exchange ActiveSync.

I've done a great deal of searching on this subject, but everything I've found is a year or more old, and relates to people *wanting* the GAL to update their iPhone automatically but having to rely on third-party solutions.  So has Apple recently made a change in iOS that syncs the GAL automatically?  And if so, how do I stop it?

Some more info: we're running Exchange 2010 on Server 2008 R2, and the exec is also using Outlook 2010 on Windows 7.  He also has an Apple Watch.